# How to print a 1D array of class module type to a range in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a class module called LotData that defines 12 public variables.  I then create an array called Buys() of type LotData and fill it with numBuys items. (0 to numBuys -1)

I'm having trouble printing Buys() to a range.  I've seen a few examples here that make it seem easy, but I keep running into errors.

Update:  This is the whole subroutine.  If there's a better way to do this, I'm all ears.  Maybe after I sort *transactions,* I should just copy the Buy rows to a *temp* sheet, rearrange the columns, and then copy that to my final destination?

```
Option Private Module

Sub HandlePurchases()

Sheets("master_holdings").Select

Dim lastRowM As Long
lastRowM = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
lastRowM = IIf(lastRowM = 1048576, 1, lastRowM)

Sheets("transactions").Select

Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
lastRow = IIf(lastRow = 1048576, 1, lastRow)

Range("A1:Z" + CStr(lastRow)).Sort Key1:=Range("A1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Key2:=Range("F1"), Order2:=xlAscending, Key3:=Range("H1"), Order3:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

Dim firstBuy As Long
Dim lastBuy As Long
Dim Buys() As LotData
Dim numBuys As Long
Dim i As Integer

firstBuy = Columns("A").Find("Buy", , xlValues, , xlRows, xlNext).Row
lastBuy = Columns("A").Find("Buy", , xlValues, , xlRows, xlPrevious).Row

numBuys = lastBuy - firstBuy + 1

ReDim Preserve Buys(numBuys - 1)

i = 0

For Row = firstBuy To lastBuy
    Set Buys(i) = New LotData
    Buys(i).Ticker = Cells(Row, 5)
    Buys(i).CUSIP = Cells(Row, 14)
    Buys(i).AcctNum = Cells(Row, 3)
    Buys(i).AcctName = Cells(Row, 4)
    Buys(i).Asset = Cells(Row, 6)
    Buys(i).OpenDate = Cells(Row, 2)
    Buys(i).StartDate = Cells(Row, 2)
    Buys(i).StartUnits = Cells(Row, 8)
    Buys(i).StartFMV = Cells(Row, 10)
    Buys(i).StartCB = Cells(Row, 10)
    Buys(i).CurrentFMV = Cells(Row, 10)
    Buys(i).CurrentUnits = Cells(Row, 8)

    i = i + 1
Next

Sheets("test").Activate

Dim myRange As Range
Set myRange = Sheets("test").Range("A1:L" & numBuys)

'Attempt 1
    'myRange = Buys
'Run-time error 1004: Application-defined or object defined error

'Attempt 2
    'Worksheets("test").Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").Offset(UBound(Buys, 1), UBound(Buys, 2))).Value = Buys
'UBound(Buys, 2) causes causes Run-time error 9: Subscript out of range

'Attempt 3
    'Worksheets("test").Range("A1").Resize(UBound(Buys, 1) + 1, UBound(Buys, 2) + 1).Value = Buys
'Same result as Attempt 2

'Attempt 4
    'myRange.Resize(UBound(Buys, 1), UBound(Buys, 2)).Value = Buys
'Same as Attempts 2 and 3

'Attempt 5
myRange.Resize(Ubound(Buys) + 1, 1).value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Buys)
'Methond Transpose of object WorksheetFunction failed

End Sub
```

Comment: You did not copy correctly the line from my code. See my updated answer. Without the variant for 2D array, after I understood what array type your code uses.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try:

Your array looks to be 1D type:

```
myRange.Resize(Ubound(Buys) + 1, 1).value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Buys)
```

If still error related with `WorksheetFunction`, try, please:

```
myRange.Resize(Ubound(Buys) + 1, 1).value = Application.Transpose(Buys)
```

Replace your 5 attempt (`myRange.Resize(UBound(Buys, 1), 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Buys)`) with the above line!

Comment: The first one resulted in the same Subscript out of range error.  The second gave me "Method 'Transpose' of object 'WorksheetFunction' failed.  I'll update my question with the whole subroutine.  I'm probably doing something else wrong.

Comment: @Mandy Sanders: How did you declare `Buys` variable and how do you populate it? Try putting in front of the above line: `Debug.Print Ubound(Buys)`. What does it return in Immediate Window?

Comment: Debug.Print UBound(Buys) = 28

Comment: @Mandy Sanders: Try, please also: `Debug.Print Ubound(Buys, 1), Ubound(Buys, 2))`. And you did not answer the questions regarding variable declaration and the way of populating...

Comment: Sorry.  I updated the original question with the full subroutine.  The only thing I didn't include is the class module for lotData, but all it does is declare variables.

Comment: Debug.Print UBound(Buys, 1) = 28 and Debug.Print UBound(Buys, 2) = Subscript out of range

Comment: So, your array is 1D. Try the single line of code. The previous time it was a mistake (Buys1 instead of Buys)...

Comment: I guess you're right about it being a 1D array.  The output will definitely be 2D, though.  I tried your updated line of code, but still got the transpose error.

Comment: Strange... Then, try `Application.Transpose` instead of `WorksheetFunction.Transpose`. I do not imagine what reference you are missing not recognizing WorksheetFunction...

Comment: @Mandy Sanders: What type of data does your array keep? Are there long strings? Longer then 254 characters?

Comment: No.  The strings are all fairly small.

Comment: Public Ticker As String
Public CUSIP As String
Public AcctNum As String
Public AcctName As String
Public Asset As String
Public OpenDate As Date
Public StartDate As Date
Public StartUnits As Double
Public StartFMV As Double
Public StartCB As Double
Public CurrentFMV As Double
Public CurrentUnits As Double

Comment: @Mandy Sanders: Is it possible to be a error string inside the arrary? Try please `Dim El As Variant`  then loop between all elements: `For each El in Buys`  `Debug.Print El` `Next`. What does it return in `Immediate Window`?

Comment: "Object doesn't support this property or method".  I really appreciate your patience and willingness to help, but I think I'm just going to move the Buys to a temp sheet, rearrange the columns, and then copy the range to its final destination.  At least I know that will work.  I should probably just delete this whole question.

Comment: @Mandy Sanders:  this only could mean that your array contains strange elements... Did you put the above recommended code on 4 lines? I usually try solving a problem I am involved in... But did you try the variant with `Application` instead of `WorksheetFunction`? If it also returned an error, certainly your array is ill...

Comment: Yes... 4 lines.  I also tried  myRange.Resize(UBound(Buys) + 1, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(Buys) results in "Object doesn't support this property or method".  When I put a Watch on Buys, it looks fine.... Buys(0) - Buys(28), each with the correct data in all 12 attributes.

Comment: @Mandy Sanders: In order to split the problem between the array itself and your system/VBA/installation, I would suggest the next test: `Dim arrTest as variant` `arrTest = Split("1,2,3,4", ",")` followed by `myRange.Resize(UBound(arrRest) + 1, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(arrRest)`. If it drops the array content, let us focus on the way of your array loading, if you receives a similar error, your Office installation has a problem which must be solved...